# Ajustar botón al final de card dinámicamente

Tags: css

Estoy tratando de lograr poner los botones en una lista de cards al final de la misma en su lado derecho, pero no puedo ajustarla verticalmente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

quedando de esa forma.

css:

```
.boton {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  left: -10px;
}

.card {
  float: left;
  margin: 1px;
  padding: 10px 3px;
  width: 15em;
  min-height: 15em;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  max-height: auto;
}
.mat-card-content {
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

UPDATE
pude hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

cree una div donde puse el botón con este estilo

```
.btn-cont {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

luego al botón:

```
.btn-go {
  float: right;
  left: -10px;
  position: relative;
  top: -10px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No te entiendo, ¿Quieres que el botón este centrado a la derecha? Así parece estar o ¿Quieres que esté centrado horizontalmente?

Comment: Entonces lo único que buscas es eliminar ese pequeño espacio a la derecha entre el botón y el borde del card no?

Comment: Hola, el problema es que este verticalmente al final de la card. Esta puede variar en su largo. Gracias @BetaM :) (va devuelta)

Comment: Me alegra que lo lograas, aunque tu código no es el ideal, estas usando css innecesario, otro ya casi descontinuado, usas "justify-content: space-between;" cuando tu contenedor no está "display: flex;" usas" top" y "right " cuando tu contenedor es "realative " tienes varias cosas que pulir

Comment: Muchas gracias @Elboy voy a mejorarlo!